# Make a part of EditText clickable?

Tags: android

I have an EditText with a 9-patched background :
[image]
Is it possible to make the search icon clickable ?
Thank you !

Comment: No, not that way.  How would the edit text know what part of a 9 patch background is the search icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure it's possible if you override `boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)`. However, in practice I think you'll have a much easier time if you put an `ImageView` with the search icon to the right of the `EditText`, and just implement on click for the `ImageView`.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_search_category_default"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The problem with onTouch is knowing what area to count, and not overlaying it with text.  This right answer is this.

Comment: You could always add right padding to ensure that the text would not cover the image... but it's still not a pattern I recommend :)

Comment: Thank you, @GabeSechan isn't it possible to make only the part of the icon clickable (which is the non scallable part of the 9 patch image) ?

Comment: No.  Touch handling works on views, not drawables.  Views have no idea what the drawable it uses as a background is like.  In addition, EditTexts have their own onTouch handling that would prevent it from ever going to the background